# Unable to cast object of type 'system.windows.forms.textbox' to type 'System.IConvertible' error for c# form

Tags: c#, object, casting

I have this code here but I keep getting the same error. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double gallonsToBuy;//for equation
    double WALL_LENGTH; //holds wall length
    double WALL_HEIGHT; //holds wall height
    int    NUM_DOORS;   //holds number of doors
    int    NUM_WINDOWS; //holds number of windows
    int    NUM_COATS;   //holds number of coats of paint
    const double GALLON_SF = 350; //one gallon covers 350 square feet

    //allows user to input their numbers
    WALL_LENGTH = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1);
    WALL_HEIGHT = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2);
    NUM_DOORS =   Convert.ToInt32(textBox3);
    NUM_WINDOWS = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4);
    NUM_COATS =   Convert.ToInt32(textBox5);

    //Equation
    gallonsToBuy = ((((WALL_LENGTH * WALL_HEIGHT) - (20 * NUM_DOORS) - (15 * NUM_WINDOWS)) * NUM_COATS) /350);

    label7.Text = "Gallons to buy =" +gallonsToBuy;
}
```

Comment: Please don't try to paraphrase error messages. Copy the message from the debugger, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46437200/edit) your question and paste it in.

Comment: `textBox1.Text`!!!!! and not `textBox1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I believe textBox1,textBox1 etc. are TextBox control. You cannot covert control type to data type. you need to use the property .text to access the value within the control.

```
    WALL_LENGTH = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    WALL_HEIGHT = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
    NUM_DOORS =   Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
    NUM_WINDOWS = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
    NUM_COATS =   Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
```

Make sure you have a value to the input fields otherwise it will through cast error trying to convert it from string.empty.

Answer (score 2):

Your error comes from trying to convert a `TextBox` to a `double`.

```
WALL_LENGTH = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1);
```

`TextBox` is a .NET object type, and you cannot do a meaningful conversion to a double. What you must do is convert the value of `TextBox.Text` property to a `double`.

```
WALL_LENGTH = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
```

But this alone would still be problematic and error prone, if the user enters text that cannot be converted to a `double`.

So you should, in addition, use proper methods for conversion such as `int.TryParse()` and `double.TryParse()`.

For instance,

```
double WALL_LENGTH;
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out WALL_LENGTH);
```

If all such conversions succeed, then proceed with the calculation.